# How avoid cell wrapping in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

First, sorry for quality of this question, but explain what I want to achieve is quite hard, that's way I've prepared [Sample code](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z1RV9).

There You can see two main columns: `#main-left-column` and `#main-right-column`.

On that `#main-right-column` I've placed six green cells and everything works as Bootstrap authors wants, but I want somehow add `'overlay-x:auto'` CSS property on my right column to avoid cell wrapping.

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

Put right `<div>` (columns inside `#main-right-column`) into `<table>` container and set minimal width.

CSS:

```
.width-300-450 {
    min-width:300px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:450px
}
```

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="width-300-450">
                <div class="col-xs-12 bg-success">
                    <h2>test</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 bg-warning">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="width-300-450">
                <div class="col-xs-12 bg-success">
                    <h2>test</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 bg-warning">
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On `#main-right-column` You must set `overlay-x` property:

```
#main-right-column {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
}
```

Full example here: [Bootstrap fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/leSFjhr38S)